# Rider automatically formats List initializer to not contain spaces causing compilation errors

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

When I write following code in Rider:

`new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() }` and I type `;` at the end, Rider automatically formats this into `new List<Guid> {Guid.NewGuid()};`

Note that spaces were removed before and after both braces.

Compiler doesn't like it and reports `[SA1012] Opening brace should be followed by a space.` and `[SA1013] Closing brace should be preceded by a space.`

How can I turn off such behavior in Rider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of Rider you're using but in 2022.2.3 I had to enable the following property under *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C#*:
[image]

I hope it helps you as well!